Why isn't my genetic algorithm converging to the global minimum on the Easom function?
I'm implementing a genetic algorithm to optimize benchmark functions like Easom, Ackley and Three-Hump camel. However, it struggles to converge to the global minimum, and instead returns values that are far off (e.g. for Easom function, [1.19, 0.81] with a fitness of -2.51e-05, instead of f(π, π) = -1). Similarly, the results for Ackley function are also not ideal (e.g. [-0.10, -0.007] with a fitness of 0.56, instead of f(0, 0) = 0).
Here's a part of my genetic algorithm, where I suspect issues in parent selection, offspring selection for new population or parameter tuning might be leading to poor convergence.
Parent Selection
def select_parents(population, fitness, method):
    if method == "PM":  # Panmixia
        return random.sample(population, k=2)
    elif (
        method == "SE"
    ):  # Selective based on fitness: Parents with fitness below average fitness
        avg_fitness = np.mean(fitness)
        parents = [ind for ind, fit in zip(population, fitness) if fit < avg_fitness]
        if len(parents) < 2:
            if len(parents) == 0:
                return random.sample(
                    population, k=2
                )  # Fallback to random sampling from the entire population
            else:
                # return parents[0], parents[0]
                return parents[0], random.choice(population)
        return random.sample(parents, k=2)
    elif method == "ID":  # Inbreeding
        parent1 = random.choice(population)
        parent2 = min(population, key=lambda x: hamming_distance(parent1, x))
        return parent1, parent2
    elif method == "OD":  # Outbreeding
        parent1 = random.choice(population)
        parent2 = max(population, key=lambda x: hamming_distance(parent1, x))
        return parent1, parent2

Children Selection
# Simple selection (SS), Selection with displacement (SD), Elite selection (ES)
def form_new_population(population, offspring, method, fitness_func):
    if method == "SS":  # Simple selection
        return offspring
    elif method == "SD":  # Selection with displacement (unique individuals)
        # Convert lists to tuples to make them hashable for set operations
        unique_offspring = list(map(tuple, offspring))
        unique_offspring = list(set(unique_offspring))
        unique_offspring = list(map(list, unique_offspring))

        if len(unique_offspring) < len(population):
            additional_offspring = random.sample(
                offspring, len(population) - len(unique_offspring)
            )
            unique_offspring.extend(additional_offspring)

        return random.sample(unique_offspring, len(population))
    elif method == "ES":  # Elite selection
        combined = population + offspring
        combined_fitness = evaluate_population(combined, fitness_func)
        elite_indices = np.argsort(combined_fitness)[: len(population)]
        return [combined[i] for i in elite_indices]

Main loop of the algorithm
 for _ in range(pop_size // 2):
            # Parent selection
            parent1, parent2 = select_parents(
                binary_population, fitness, parent_selection_method
            )

            # (crossover, mutation, inversion)
            child1, child2 = process_children(
                parent1,
                parent2,
                crossover_type,
                mutation_rate,
                inversion_rate,
                CROSSOVER_CHANCE,
            )

            # convert back to float
            decoded_child1 = decode_individual(child1, limits, n_bits)
            decoded_child2 = decode_individual(child2, limits, n_bits)

            children.append(decoded_child1)
            children.append(decoded_child2)

        # Children selection for new population
        population = form_new_population(
            population, children, population_formation, func
        )

        # Evaluate fitness for the new population
        fitness = evaluate_population(population, func)

        current_best = min(fitness)

        # the best solution for the current iteration
        best_solution_history.append(population[fitness.index(current_best)])

        fitness_history.append(current_best)
        iteration += 1

    overall_best = min(fitness_history)
    best_overall_solution = best_solution_history[fitness_history.index(overall_best)]

I have posted the full code with graph showing the fitness values over generations on my Github.
What factors should I consider adjusting in my algorithm to improve convergence? Are there known best practices for parameter tuning on functions like Easom?
